How to put Bibliography to this Table format?
Code
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % before hyperref 
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{xurl} % after biblatex
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\overfullrule=1mm
\pretolerance=-1
%\tolerance=1
%\badness=0

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

Hello world: 
\printbibliography

Make here a table for Bibliography where columns: 
Number of Reference | Title |  Note | Date 

\end{document}

bib2.bib
@article{2307111.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf,
author = {Lorem lorem and Lorem Loremlorem},
note = {\path{230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf}, \path{230711 lorem11 lorem.YHTEINEN TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf}},
date = {2023-07-11},
title = {Mittausp\"{o}yt\"{a}kirja. Yhteisen tiealueen maaty\"{o}t 11.7.2023.}
}
@article{211110.heppuu.heppu.APUPOHJA.SUODATINRENGAS.NOTAARIUSKERROKSEN.PAKSUUS.pdf,
    author = {Heppuu Lassi},
    note = {
    \path{231110.heppuu.hukka.APUPOHJA.SUODATINRENGAS.NOTAARIUSKERROKSEN.PAKSUUS.pdf}
    },
    date = {2023-11-10},
    title = {Mittausp\"{o}yt\"{a}kirja. Tasolasermittaukset: apupohjan suodatinrenkaan korkeusasemat, notaariuskerroksen paksuus. 
    10.11.2021.}
}

Output now:

Wanted output in table form:
Number of Reference | Title |  Note | Date 

OS: Debian latest
